# tcl/informix fetch for db and display in a tabular form

Tags: tcl, informix

I have to write this code in tcl and I am really frustrated because This is my first time in tcl. I need to display something like this:[image]

I am using tcl/informix and I am struggling a bit as how to achieve the above. Here is a pseudocode I wrote

```
    select event_date,attempts_cnt,success_cnt,fail_cnt from cc_web_ppv_counts WHERE 
        event_id='123' 
    {
        get $sd_attempt_cnt
        get $sd_success_cnt
        get $sd_fail_cnt
            get event_date




        select event_date,attempts_cnt,success_cnt,fail_cnt from cc_web_ppv_counts WHERE 
            event_id='125' 
        {
            get $hd_attempt_cnt
            get $hd_success_cnt
            get $hd_fail_cnt

            $total_attempts=$sd_attempt_cnt + $hd_attempt_cnt;
            $total_success=$sd_success_cnt + $hd_success_cnt;
            $total_fail=$total_attempts -$total_success;
            $success_rate=($total_success/$total_attempts)*100;
            $hd_success_rate=($hd_success_cnt/total_success)*100;
            $sd_success_rate=($sd_success_cnt/total_success)*100;
        }
    }
```

Note There for each event_date(for example today) there would be only 2 records.for sd and hd respectively.so the dates have to be displayed dynamically in the output.

I would appreciate if somone could point out to some examples in tcl that pulls data and displays like above.

Comment: You need a SQL cursor to loop through each event_date and process the data per day. You should be able to do it all in 1 SQL statement, but I'm familiar with Informix to be honest. If you explain a little more about what technology you're using, you'll probably get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [tclodbc](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2151) with a proper ODBC driver is a way to go.

As to the second part of the question, the answer heavily depends on how do you define "display".